# AWS Aurora is only recording newlines into the error log on failed logins

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, error-logging, amazon-aurora

Is anyone else having this problem?

I have enabled Cloudwatch logging and toggled publishing to on for general, audit, slow and error logs, *BUT I NEVER SEE ENTRIES FOR FAILED LOGINS*.

Perhaps AWS-RDS filtering on error logs is TOO aggressive!

The following example tries to log in as a bogus user and show something that does not exist (in this case the BINLOGS)

This SHOULD generate two entries for failed logins.

All I actually get is a bunch of newlines (\n), proportional in count to the number of failed logins.

```
sh-4.2$  mysql -utoot -pPoot -hMY_INSTANCE_NAME.cum0ld45s8ef.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -e "SHOW BINARY LOGS;"; mysql -utoot -pPoot -hMY_INSTANCE_NAME.cum0ld45s8ef.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -e "SHOW BINARY LOGS;"
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'toot'@'172.31.64.XX' (using password: YES)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'toot'@'172.31.64.XX' (using password: YES)
sh-4.2$ aws rds download-db-log-file-portion --db-instance-identifier MY_INSTANCE_NAME --no-paginate --log-file-name error/mysql-error-running.log{
    "Marker": "15:106",
    "AdditionalDataPending": false,
    "LogFileData": "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
```

Comment: What's the value of the sysvar `@@log_warnings`?  If < 2 then I wouldn't expect failed logins to be written to the error log unless Aurora is departing from standard behavior.

Comment: That was the missing link! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not write failed login attempts to the error log, unless the `log_warnings` system variable has a value > 1.

> If the value is greater than 1, aborted connections are written to the error log, and access-denied errors for new connection attempts are written.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_warnings

In Aurora, this behavior is the same, but `log_warnings` is configured via the instance [parameter group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.html#AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set "log_warnings" to a value greater than 2, like, say, 3.
In AWS Aurora this is configured via the instance parameter group